# How to shuffle an ArrayList

Tags: java, list, collections

I need some help in writing a method that will shuffle the ArrayList. I can't figure out what to place in my method. Here is what I have so far. I tried using the random method to randomize the integers in the list but that didn't work. Can someone show me how to do this?

Here is the code I've tried:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab 11 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);   
    System.out.print("Enter integers (input ends with 0): ");
     double value;

    do {
      value = input.nextDouble(); // Read a value from the input

      if (value != 0) 
        list.add(value); // Add the value if it is not in the list
    } while (value != 0);
     System.out.println("The maximum number is " + max(list));

     System.out.print("Enter five double values: ");
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      list.add(input.nextDouble());

    System.out.println("The sum is " + sum(list));

  }

  public static Double max(ArrayList<Double> list) {
    if (list == null || list.size() == 0)
      return null;

    double result = list.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++)
      if (result < list.get(i))
        result = list.get(i);

    return result;
  }

  public static double sum(ArrayList<Double> list) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
      sum += list.get(i);
    return sum;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use [`Collections#shuffle(List list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm

Comment: I don't see you using the "_random method_" anywhere at all.  It looks like you haven't tried anything and have simply pasted your last assignment into the question box.  Please put in some effort and only ask a question when you have something specific to ask.  There are many questions on this site that explain how to randomize a list.

Comment: Why would I put the random method in there if it didn't work? I obviously put some effort into if I have almost the whole assignment done, I just didn't know how to do this one part.

Comment: Whatever you say... But, there is no evidence in your code that you've attempted to solve the problem in question.  Best of luck!  Luckily for you, multiple people have told you exactly how to do what you want.  Note there are also dozens of identical questions on this site.

Comment: "Why would I put the random method in there if it didn't work?" So we can help you fix it, that's why.

Comment: Please accept the answer which helped you most in solving your problem. It helps future readers. If the answers weren't helpful leave comments below them. So the poster can update them accordingly. Read [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to know more.

Answer (score 249):

Use this method and pass your array in parameter

```
Collections.shuffle(arrayList);
```

This method return void so it will not give you a new list but as we know that array is passed as a reference type in Java so it will shuffle your array and save shuffled values in it. That's why you don't need any return type.

You can now use arraylist which is shuffled.

Comment: How do you then print out the result of that shuffled ArrayList?

Comment: @santafebound Arrays.toString(arrayList.toArray());

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [_How do I write a good answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.

Comment: Below is an example of what Collections.shuffle(arrayList) does, and a way to print the result before and after shuffling:
public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        ArrayList<String>  mylist = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        mylist.add("code"); 
        mylist.add("quiz"); 
        mylist.add("geeksforgeeks"); 
        mylist.add("quiz"); 
        mylist.add("practice"); 
        mylist.add("qa"); 
        System.out.println("Original List : " + mylist); 
        Collections.shuffle(mylist); 
        System.out.println("Shuffled List : " + mylist);
    }

Answer (score 34):

Try [Collections.shuffle(list)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29).If usage of this method is barred for solving the problem, then one can look at the actual implementation.

Comment: Obviously this is a homework assignment....

Comment: If so, then the OP can go through the actual implementation of this method by referring to the rt.jar

Comment: Ok, I have removed the code!

Comment: At least if you make him find the source code he'll have to put in **some** effort and learn **something**...