# Retrieve mcq data from firebase realtime database with options

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve my mcq from firebase realtime database in my android app.

Below is the code for the same.

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Questions").child(String.valueOf(computerCount));
                 
                databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        final Question question = dataSnapshot.getValue(Question.class);
                        questionTxt.setText(question.getQuestion());
                        b1.setText(question.getOption1());
                        b2.setText(question.getOption2());
                        b3.setText(question.getOption3());
                        b4.setText(question.getOption4());


                        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                if(b1.getText().toString().equals(question.answer))
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Correct answer",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                    correct = correct +1;
                                    Handler handler = new Handler();

                                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#03A9F4"));
                                            updateQuestion();
                                        }
                                    }, 1500);

                                }
```

I want this to fetch in random way instead of sequential way  ex: 1,2

my json is like  :
[image: Structure]

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect? Please also add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: my json is like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/CijIR.png  i want this to fetch in random way instead of sequential way ex: 1,2,3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can retrieve all of your mcq's and saved them in an arraylist and later using

```
Collections.shuffle(arrayList);
```

you can shuffle them.
To know more about shuffle and usage you can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16112539/8678995)